# Kubernetes coredns pods go into "Completed" state after rebooting the OS

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I have Kubernetes 1.19.6 setup on an OracleLinux 8.3 system. There is only one node on the system.

All of the kube-system pods are in a Running state and everything on the system behaves as expected. However, after running the "reboot" command on the system, once the system comes back up, the coredns pods are in a "Completed" state.

```
[myuser@kubernetesol ~]$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                   READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74bf74b8d7-5q4jk               0/1     Completed   0          14h
coredns-74bf74b8d7-htghm               0/1     Completed   0          14h
etcd-kubernetesol                      1/1     Running     1          14h
kube-apiserver-kubernetesol            1/1     Running     1          14h
kube-controller-manager-kubernetesol   1/1     Running     1          14h
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-phwgm            1/1     Running     2          14h
kube-flannel-ds-r2nm9                  1/1     Running     1          14h
kube-proxy-x8jvw                       1/1     Running     1          14h
kube-scheduler-kubernetesol            1/1     Running     1          14h
```

```
[myuser@kubernetesol ~]$ kubectl logs coredns-74bf74b8d7-5q4jk -f -n kube-system
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = ff8c5872df7452e9a97d02187b75796f
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
[INFO] SIGTERM: Shutting down servers then terminating
```

If I were to delete the coredns pods, then they would go back into Running state and behave correctly. However, is there a way to make it so that the coredns pods come back up automatically when rebooting the system?

Comment: How did you bootstrap you cluster? Was it kubeadm? Is there any more information needed before i will try to reproduce your scenario?

Comment: We use kubeadm to setup the cluster. I'm new to setting up cluster, so let me know what other information I can provide.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I was using quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-amd64. After updating to quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.12.0-amd64 I no longer see this issue.